# is it possible to trigger oozie workflow just and only with a message ( ie with kafka)

Tags: apache-kafka, oozie, eventtrigger

I would like to by-pass *starttime* and *frequency* parameter to get  workflow started  immediatly when the  message is received from the kafka broker.
is is possible to add some plugin/class to oozie to realize this ?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a consumer to submit an Oozie workflow since Oozie does not have such an event-driven coordinator.

NiFi would be more inline with what you're trying to do